# Hive truncating the column data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table in hive. The structure is below:

```
vid varchar(2)
vname varchar(10)
```

If i load below data in hive,

```
123,xyz
111,anc
21,pqr
```

Only one record should be inserted in hive but all 3 records and truncating the vid values from 123 to 12 and 111 to 11.

Can anyone provide any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't filter the data that can be inserted, it only truncates the data that exceed the defined length in your columns. There is a misunderstanding about the Hive behavior. If you want restrict the fields to be inserted you will need to filter the rows using `length()` and the max expected field size.